# Trying to make a script where you cant move further down when you have reached a certain height

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using the code below, I get the following error:

> Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Vector3' and 'int'

The code:

```
void PlayerTurn()
{
    if(state != BattleState.PLAYERTURN) 
    {
        return;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("w")) 
    {

    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("s") && player.transform.position < -3)
    {
            
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `player.transform.position` field seems to be of type `Vector3`. What are the properties of that type?

Answer (score 1):

`player.transform.position` is a `Vector3`, a 3 dimensional vector

`-3` is an `int`, 1 dimensional integer

`<` is the `is less then` operator.

You cannot "compare" those 2 types like that without defining a rule for it.

For example, you could take the absolute value of the vector, and compare that with an `int`, but that still leaves you with handling the `-` sign since the modulus is always positive.

---

Alternatively, if you're talking about a specific axis of the 3 dimensional vector, it will be something like:

```
//using `y` since you mentioned height.
player.transform.position.y < -3f
```